# Jquery addClass not working in the document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

The upper `addclass` (Red section), is not working, but the bottom function (Redsection 2), is doing just fine, and the `document.ready` is working (it's outputting the load.).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#1").addClass("active");
  var url = "klanten_load_klant.php?uid=" + 1;
  $(".load").load(url, function() {});
});

function loadCustomer(uid) {
  var url = "klanten_load_klant.php?uid=" + uid;
  $(".load").load(url, function() {});
  $("tr").removeClass("active");
  $("#" + uid).addClass("active");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col l3 m4 s12 card #212121 grey darken-4 white-text">
  <h5>Klanten</h5>
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" onkeyup="filter()" placeholder="Zoek naar een klant.." title="Typ een voor/achternaam.">
  <div id="input">
    <table id="customerTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Klantcode</th>
          <th>Naam</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table-body">
        <tr onclick="loadCustomer(this.id)" id="1">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Herman Grendelman</td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="loadCustomer(this.id)" id="2">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Dion Grendelman</td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="loadCustomer(this.id)" id="3">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Test Account</td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="loadCustomer(this.id)" id="4">
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Liselot Meiland</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML. We need a [mcve] in your question

Comment: Updated it @j08691

Comment: this line `$("#1").addClass("active");` is working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/v5fv3smu/ I can able to see the active class added in `#1`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the solution to your load() issue - but you can clean up the code somewhat by including a click handler on the tr from the jquery (rather than inline within the HTML) and getting the id of the tr that was clicked. Note that I have added a red color to the active class to demonstrate the effect of clicking on the tr's.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#1").addClass("active");
  var url = "klanten_load_klant.php?uid=" + 1;
  $(".load").load(url, function() {});
});


$('tr').click(function(){
  var uid = $(this).attr('id');
  var url = "klanten_load_klant.php?uid=" + uid;
  $(".load").load(url, function() {});
  $("tr").removeClass("active");
  $("#" + uid).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col l3 m4 s12 card #212121 grey darken-4 white-text">
  <h5>Klanten</h5>
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" onkeyup="filter()" placeholder="Zoek naar een klant.." title="Typ een voor/achternaam.">
  <div id="input">
    <table id="customerTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Klantcode</th>
          <th>Naam</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table-body">
        <tr id="1">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Herman Grendelman</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Dion Grendelman</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="3">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Test Account</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="4">
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Liselot Meiland</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```